# How to keep user logged to Facebook when switching from iOS FB to Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have app on AppStore that uses native iOS 6.0 Facebook account (in settings). Now I will release new version that is using Facebook SDK instead. There are users who logged in via native iOS framework and now I want Facebook SDK in the new version when installed to "import" those users from system without showing any login dialogs. 
Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to go to your app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

And then edit it.On the basic definitions your app can be cross platform I have apps that are facebook app, mobile app and page tab. If you grant permission in one of them, the user can  enter all the 3 without asking permissions again.

Comment: I updated question, making it more clear, I think your answer is related to another situation, but thanks anyway.

Comment: as long as you use the same app id, you can change the SDK

Comment: I see, you're right, it works seamless if correct methods are called in correct way. Thanks. The bad thing here is that for some reason FacebookSDK method  "FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:" does not call that completion handler if allowLoginUI is NO. I had to use solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749027/importing-users-facebook-credentials-into-ios6 but I think that's a topic for another SO question.

Comment: Glad I could help you out, about your second question I can't help you out, I haven't done anything to iOS, yet.